# Can I set up Wordpress Multisite where one of the subdomains has ssl?

Tags: multisite, ssl

I would like to install wordpress multisite on a live server and have one of the sub-domains be https.  The main site is not https and neither are the other sub-domains. Is that possible?  Thanks!

Comment: Are your sub-sites in sub-directory or sub-domain format? Are you domain mapping to the any of the sub-sites that need SSL? It should be possible depending on your setup.

Comment: I'm actually reinstalling fresh so I can do either.  The host I use has the subdomains set up as subdirectories though, and the ssl certificate is set to that subdirectory.  IE: http://example.com,when I look at my FTP, it shows public_html/mainwebsite.com,  public_html/mainwebsite.com/secondwebsite.com/index.php 

where it is http://mainwebsite.com and https://secondwebsite.com  (sorry I'm seeing the ht_tp and ht_tps is dropping in this comment...secondwebsite.com is ht_tps...

Comment: If you're doing domain mapping for sub-sites (e.g. yourseconddomain.com is mapped to yourdomain.com/subsite) then your SSL cert should be keyed to yourseconddomain.com and using some WP plugins, you should be able to enable SSL for that sub-site. [Here's an example for such plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ssl-subdomain-for-multisite/).

Comment: great-so my situation is indeed a subdirectory and not subdomain install?

Comment: sub-domain would be like subsite.yourdomain.com. But if you're mapping domains (e.g. yourseconddomain.com is mapped to subsite.yourdomain.com), then it really won't matter as the SSL cert is generally domain specific. So long as yourseconddomain.com is mapped to a sub-site and you use that plugin, you should be good.

Comment: FWIW, I know that this site isn't about plugin recommendations, but I did find this plugin that work for you as well: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/installation/

Comment: I've just done a plugin for wordpress that does actually that. You may have a look and download it for free int this link: http://arturoemilio.es/2013/07/23/login-en-wordpress-a-traves-de-un-subdominio-ssl/